# Maximum of derivatives of a differentiable function

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I am preparing for the "concours aux grandes écoles" and I was looking for some problems on analysis. These problem are hard but I generally am able to solve them. However, I am stuck on a problem since this morning and have absolutely no idea about how to solve it. I am new to this forum so do not blame me if I express myself incorrectly or in the wrong feed. Here is the problem.

Let $n\geq 2$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $\mathcal{C}^n$ function. For any $0\leq k\leq n$ define $$M_k=\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}\vert f^{(k)}(t)\vert.$$ Suppose that $M_0$ and $M_n$ are finite. Show that $$M_k < +\infty$$ for every $k$. Show furthermore that $$M_1 \leq \sqrt{2M_0 M_2}.$$

For the second one, Taylor at the left and at the right of some point $x$, up to $2$nd derivative. This gives me $$f'(x)\leq \frac{2M_0}{2h}+\frac{h}{4}2M_2$$
Thank to Ted Shifrin, I noticed that I can get the second inequality by just minimizing the bound over $h$, silly me !
Doing this, I get the desired bound. However, I have still no idea how to do the first question.

Comment: I'm  not sure about the constants, since you didn't show your work, but if that inequality holds for all $h>0$, what is the minimum of that function of $h$?

Comment: Thank you ! I edit.

Comment: Hint : try to solve it for $n=2$. You can just isolate $f'(x)$ in this case using Taylor expansion. Try to do the same for $n=3$. Now you cannot isolate $f'$ and $f''$ in your expansion because you have different coefficient. How can you get rid of these coefficients ?